# Robot Frame work in Linux

Tags: python, robotframework

How to get the status of the command which is executed in linux with the help of robot frame work.
For example If use this:

```
SSHLibrary open Connection (server)
SSHLibrary login  xxxxx  xxxxx
${1111}= Write ${command}
${2222}= Read  delay=5s
```

In the above script how to get the status of the command I have executed and stored in the ${1111} var,

Eg; If command executed pass the I have to get a status with 0 otherwise 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Execute command](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command) instead of [Write](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Write)

The [SSHLibrary documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html) gives this example:

```
${rc}=    Execute Command    echo Success guaranteed.    return_stdout=False    return_rc=True
Should Be Equal    ${rc}    ${0}
```

Comment: I have tried that one it is not working. And at the same time I need the out put to be stored in the other  variable for further process.