# Appending new data in remote file using robotframework

Tags: ssh, robotframework

I am trying to append a data in to a file which is a remote server.
There is a keyword in robotframework that can append data in to a file locally(that is on the same server where I am executing the script).
As of now I am using remote server library to execute commands on the remote console.

How to get access that file using remote server?
Hot to append data using remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Robot Framework's [SSH library](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html) to do this. Looking at your previous questions, it looks like you're [already using this library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45101647/8332700).

As for writing to the file, these questions may help:

- [Appending a string to a file from remote ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296154)
- [How to append a file through ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266241)